# Powershell Script Remote Exchange Server 2013 CU 17 upgrade

Tags: wmi, exchange-server, powershell-remoting

I'm in the process of creating a script that preforms a remote upgrade of an Exchange Server 2013 from cu15 to cu17 using Powershell.

It updates .Net Framework 4.6.2 without issue.

It runs into errors after starting .\setup.exe /mode:upgrade /IAcceptExchangeServerLicenseTerms.

The setup logs indicate that it cannot verify credentials, but I am unsure as, it manages to install .net Framework without issue. The account being used in an Enterprise Admin (AD); Organisational Admin (Exchange); & a local server admin (on all exchange servers).

**Exchange setup Log file**

```
10/04/2017 09:06:27.0628] [0] **********************************************
[10/04/2017 09:06:28.0503] [0] Starting Microsoft Exchange Server 2013 Setup
[10/04/2017 09:06:28.0503] [0] **********************************************
[10/04/2017 09:06:28.0518] [0] Local time zone: (UTC+01:00) Amsterdam, Berlin, Bern, Rome, Stockholm, Vienna.
[10/04/2017 09:06:28.0518] [0] Operating system version: Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0.
[10/04/2017 09:06:28.0518] [0] Setup version: 15.0.1320.4.
[10/04/2017 09:06:28.0518] [0] Logged on user: Dev\exadmin.
[10/04/2017 09:06:30.0003] [0] Command Line Parameter Name='mode', Value='Upgrade'.
[10/04/2017 09:06:30.0003] [0] Command Line Parameter Name='iacceptexchangeserverlicenseterms', Value=''.
[10/04/2017 09:06:30.0003] [0] Command Line Parameter Name='sourcedir', Value='c:\temp\Exchange2013-x64-cu17'.
[10/04/2017 09:06:30.0081] [0] RuntimeAssembly was started with the following command: '***/mode:upgrade /IAcceptExchangeServerLicenseTerms*** /sourcedir:c:\temp\Exchange2013-x64-cu17'.
[10/04/2017 09:06:30.0081] [0] The registry key, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Exchange\v8.0, wasn't found.
[10/04/2017 09:06:30.0081] [0] The registry key, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ExchangeServer\v14, wasn't found.
[10/04/2017 09:06:30.0081] [0] Copying Files...
[10/04/2017 09:06:30.0081] [0] Starting copy from c:\temp\Exchange2013-x64-cu17\Setup\ServerRoles\Common to C:\Windows\Temp\ExchangeSetup.
[10/04/2017 09:08:48.0113] [0] Finished copy from c:\temp\Exchange2013-x64-cu17\Setup\ServerRoles\Common to C:\Windows\Temp\ExchangeSetup.
[10/04/2017 09:08:48.0113] [0] File copy complete. Setup will now collect additional information needed for installation.
[10/04/2017 09:08:48.0129] [0] Assembly dll file location is C:\Windows\Temp\ExchangeSetup\Microsoft.Exchange.Setup.Console.dll
[10/04/2017 09:08:53.0832] [0] Setup is choosing the domain controller to use
[10/04/2017 09:09:00.0067] [0] Setup is choosing a local domain controller...
[10/04/2017 09:09:00.0473] [0] Setup encountered a problem while validating the state of Active Directory: Active Directory operation failed on . The supplied credential for 'Dev\exadmin' is invalid.  See the Exchange setup log for more information on this error.
[10/04/2017 09:09:00.0473] [0] Active Directory operation failed on . The supplied credential for 'Dev\exadmin' is invalid.
[10/04/2017 09:09:00.0473] [0] The supplied credential is invalid.
[10/04/2017 09:09:00.0473] [0] Setup will use the domain controller ''.
[10/04/2017 09:09:00.0473] [0] Setup will use the global catalog ''.
```

**Script being used**

```
enter code here
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange*
Import-Module FailoverClusters
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Confirm:$false

$Path = Get-Location
$Path = $Path.ToString()
$Date = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm-ss"
$FileNameFormat = "\" + (Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm-ss") + "-CU17-Upgrade.log"
$Log = $Path + $FilenameFormat
$Log = $Log.ToString()

Start-Transcript -Path $Log -NoClobber -IncludeInvocationHeader

#Exchange Servers
$CUReady = $False
$domain = (Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem).Domain

$Location = $env:computername
$Location = $Location.ToString()
$Location = $Location.SubString(0,2)
$Location

$DAGs = Get-DatabaseAvailabilityGroup $Location*
$DAGmenu = @{}
$EXServermenu = @{}

for ($i=1;$i -le $DAGs.count; $i++) {
    Write-Host "$i. $($DAGs[$i-1].name)"
    $DAGmenu.Add($i,($DAGs[$i-1].name))
    }

[int]$Dans = Read-Host 'Choose DAG'
$DAGselection = $DAGmenu.Item($Dans)

$DAGName = Get-DatabaseAvailabilityGroup -identity $DAGselection | Select -exp Name
$DAGName = $DAGName.ToString()
#Write-Host -Fore Green $DAGName

$servers = Get-DatabaseAvailabilityGroup -identity $DAGName -status | Select -exp Servers
$servers = $servers.name
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$exchangeServers = $servers

for ($i=1;$i -le $exchangeServers.count; $i++) {
    Write-Host "$i. $($exchangeServers[$i-1])"
    $EXServermenu.Add($i,($exchangeServers[$i-1]))
    }

[int]$Eans = Read-Host 'Choose DAG'
$EXSrvselection = $EXServermenu.Item($Eans)

Write-Host -Fore Green $DAGName
Write-Host -Fore White $EXSrvselection

$exserver = $EXSrvselection

IF (Test-Connection -ComputerName $exserver -Quiet) {
write-host -Fore Green "Success! Test connection to $exserver"
} ELSE {
write-host -Fore Red "Failed! Test connection to $exserver failed. Please confirm connection and retry upgrade
Script will exit - Line 41"
exit
}

#$s = New-Pssession -Computername $exserver
                                Invoke-Command -ComputerName $exserver -ScriptBlock {

                                $exserver = [STRING] $exserver

                                If ($env:COMPUTERNAME -ne $($args[0])){

                                write-host -Fore Green "Failed! Invoke Command to $($args[0]) could not be established. Please confirm connectivity and retry upgrade
                                Script will exit - Line 52"
                                Exit
                                } ELSE {

                                $Path = Get-Location
                                $Path = $Path.ToString()

                                Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force
                                Function Get-dotNetVersion {

                                $dotNetHashTable = New-Object HashTable
                                $dotNetHashTable.Add("4.5",378389)
                                $dotNetHashTable.Add("4.5.1",378675..378758)
                                $dotNetHashTable.Add("4.5.2",379893)
                                $dotNetHashTable.Add("4.6",393295..393297)
                                $dotNetHashTable.Add("4.6.1",394254..394271)
                                $dotNetHashTable.Add("4.6.2",394802..394806)
                                $dotNetHashTable.Add("4.7",460798)

                                                $dotNetHashTable = $dotNetHashTable.GetEnumerator() | Sort-Object -Property Value
                                                return $dotNetHashTable

                                }

                                $Server = $exserver
                                $reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey("LocalMachine",$($args[0]))
                                $keyname = 'SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full'
                                $key = $reg.OpenSubkey($keyname)
                                $value = $key.GetValue('Release')
                                $dotNetFramework = $value

                                #$dotNetFramework
                                $GetDotNetVersion = (Get-dotNetVersion | Where {$_.value -eq $dotNetFramework}) | Select -exp Name

                                IF ($GetDotNetVersion -ne "4.6.2") {

        Write-host -ForegroundColor Yellow ".net version on server $($args[0]) is $GetDotNetVersion"

                                                #$dotNetFramework462 = $Path + "\dotNetFramework4.6.2\NDP462-KB3151800-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe"
                                                $dotNetFramework462 = "c:\temp\Exchange2013-x64-cu17\'dotNetFramework4.6.2'\NDP462-KB3151800-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe"

                IF (Test-Path $dotNetFramework462){
                                                                                write-host "Installing .NET 4.6..." -ForegroundColor Green


                                                                                #$dotargs = "/quiet /norestart"
                                                                                #$InstalldotNet = (Start-Process $dotNetFramework462 -ArgumentList $dotargs -Wait -PassThru).ExitCode

                                                                                                IF ($InstalldotNet -eq 0) {
                            write-host -Fore Green "Successfully installed .NET 4.6"   

                                                                                                } ELSEIF ($InstalldotNet -ne 0) { write-host -Fore Red "Failed!
                                                                                                    Script will exit, Please review / install .NetFramework 4.6.2, then upgrade"
                                                                                                    Exit
                        }

                                                                                } ELSE {

                                                                                                write-host -Fore Red "Failed! Script will exit, Please locate / install .NetFramework 4.6.2, then upgrade"
                                                                                                Exit

                                                                    }

                                                } ELSEIF ($GetDotNetVersion -eq "4.6.2") {

            Write-host -ForegroundColor Green ".net version on server $($args[0]) is $GetDotNetVersion"

                                                                $reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey("LocalMachine",$($args[0]))
                                                                $keyname = 'SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\{4934D1EA-BE46-48B1-8847-F1AF20E892C1}'
                                                                $key = $reg.OpenSubkey($keyname)
                                                                $value = $key.GetValue('DisplayVersion')
                                                                $ExVersion = $value

                                                                IF ($ExVersion -eq '15.0.1263.5') {
                                                                                Write-host "Upgrading Exchange Server 2013 - $($args[0]) to CU17..." -ForegroundColor Green

                                                                                #$excu17 = $Path + "\setup.exe"
                                                                                $excu17 = "c:\temp\Exchange2013-x64-cu17\setup.exe"

                           IF (Test-Path $excu17){
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   $exargs = "/mode:upgrade /IAcceptExchangeServerLicenseTerms"
                                                                                                   $Installexcu17 = (Start-Process $excu17 -ArgumentList $exargs -Wait -PassThru).ExitCode

                                                                                                    IF ($Installexcu17 -eq 0) {

                            write-host -Fore Green "Successfully upgraded Exchange Server 2013 - $($args[0]) to CU17..."

                            } ELSEIF ($Installexcu17 -ne 0) {

                            write-host -Fore Red "Failed!to upgraded Exchange Server 2013 - $($args[0]) to CU17...
                            Script will exit. Please review exchange upgrade logs then upgrade"
                                                                                                    Exit

                            }

                                                                                                } ELSE {

                                                                                                write-host -Fore Red "Failed!
                                                                                                Script will exit, Please locate exchange install files on Exchange Server 2013 - $($args[0]); review errors"
                                                                                                Exit
                                                                                                }

                                                                                } ELSE {

                                                                                write-host -Fore Red "Failed!
                                                                                Script will exit, Exchange server version on server - $($args[0]) is not CU15"
                                                                                Exit
                                                                }                             
                                                }
                }
} -ArgumentList $exserver
Stop-Transcript -ErrorAction Ignore
```

Comment: If use the following parameters it seems to work, by passing the credentials entered, wen prompted to enter a password. Whats the open of using the users current logon credentials and bypassing having the enter the password?  $s = New-PSSession -Computername "Server1" -Authentication CredSSP -cred domain\user -verbose

Answer (score 0):

1. To check which .net Framework is installed you can check the registry (see [here](http://www.admin-enclave.com/en/articles/windows/370-find-out-which-net-framework-version-is-installed.html) for more info's). So you could check the registry with your script to ensure that the correct framework was installed.
2. After .net is installed/Updated you need to reboot your Exchange server (see [here](http://www.admin-enclave.com/en/articles/exchange/386-cumulative-update-6-for-exchange-server-2016-released.html)) otherwise the server/setup will still detect an outdated Framework and the installation will fail. Additional once rebooted the .net Framework Optimization Service is started and I have seen that when it runs an Exchange upgrade will fail as Exchange still discover a wrong .Net Framework version. To speed up the  .net Framework Optimization Service after installation and reboot check [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2013/08/06/wondering-why-mscorsvw-exe-has-high-cpu-usage-you-can-speed-it-up/).